# The command source sandbox/bin/activate doesn't work in powershell

Tags: python, powershell, neo4j

I just start the course "Building Neo4j Applications with Python" in Neo4j Graph Academy. In the course I created a virtual environment named sandbox with `python -m venv sandbox` but when I want to activate with the code indicated in the course: `source sandbox/bin/activate` the powershell console shows this error:

```
source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file.
script or executable program. Check if you spelled the name correctly, or if you included a
path, check that the path is correct and try again.
On line: 1 Character: 1
+ source sandbox/bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException    
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: What OS are you using? What does `sandbox/Scripts/Activate.ps1` give you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are on Windows, using PowerShell, and trying to activate the virtual environment with the bash/zsh script meant for Unix systems.

Instead, try running

```
sandbox\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

You can find the full documentation with more details and things to consider here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Make sure to give it a good read.